# reflection matrix with eigenvalues 1 and -1

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ V $ be a 2-dimensional euclidean vectorspace. Show that the map $ f: V \to V$ is a reflection if, and only if the mapping has Eigenvalues $ 1$ and $-1 $ and the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

It sounds like an easy Thing to proof..but i just cant get around it.

I started with $ " \rightarrow "$ : Let
$ A =\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{pmatrix} $.

the characteristic polynomial  $ \mathbb{X}_a $ = $ \lambda ^2-1 $

so the Eigenvalues are $  \lambda  = 1,-1$
Now i cant Show that the eigenvectors are orthogonal in that form. 
Do you have any idea how to make a better proof?

Comment: Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are always orthogonal.

Comment: So how do you define a reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your matrix $A$ is a reflection if and only if $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

To finish your proof of the $\implies$ direction, it suffices (in the case of $b \neq 0$) to note that the eigenvectors will be $(-b,a-1)$ and $(-b,a+1).$  Their dot product is
$$
b^2 + (a-1)(a+1) = b^2 + a^2 - 1 = 0
$$
In the case of $b = 0$, it's easy to see what the eigenvalues are.

For a proof in the other direction: let $Q$ be the matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors, the stationary direction first, normalized to have length $1$.  Note that since $Q$ has orthonormal columns, it is orthogonal which is to say that $Q^{-1} = Q^T$.  Since $f$ has two distinct eigenvectors, it can be diagonalized as
$$
A = Q \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}Q^T
$$
Show that this product has the desired form.